# Unable to see my CenturyLink wifi network in Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: networking, internet

My household recently switched to Centurylink from Comcast. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.4. The issue I am having is I do not see MY CenturyLink wifi network in my ubuntu's list of available wifi connections. I can, however, see my neighbor's centuryilnk wifi networks as they show up in my list of available wifi networks.

I am using a C2000T modem/router. The ethernet connection works just fine. Also, I am able to connect to my CenturyLink wifi from my iPhone and several PCs (windows-based). So it does not appear to be an issue with my network, but with my OS. Is there something I need to do to activate the wifi network on my ubuntu system? Anyone have experience with this? I suspect the modem/router model may also be causing some issues.

Edit (to address the first comment below):
Sorry for the lack of info. I didn't have problems connecting to the wifi prior to switching to CenturyLink. My ubuntu machine can connect to wifi. I think my wifeless adapter info is found in the output

```
"       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
"

iwconfig outputs:
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"DANG"  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.



ifconfig outputs:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:9d:36:90  
          inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e97:eff:fe9d:3690/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49410 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41499627 (41.4 MB)  TX bytes:9556377 (9.5 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f3500000-f3520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3644 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:344581 (344.5 KB)  TX bytes:344581 (344.5 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:88:14:38:10:14  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e88:14ff:fe38:1014/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:826 (826.0 B)  TX bytes:20227 (20.2 KB)
```

I ran the script from [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
My output is too big to include in this post, so I uploaded it here:
[output](http://textuploader.com/5bvkt)

Comment: You can check band (2 GHZ vs 5 GHZ), security mode, etc to ensure all are compatible.  You don't state if you had problems connecting before the switch.  Can your machine connect to any wifi network at all?  What is your wifi adapter?  Is the hardware switch on? What is the output of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig`?Give us some details and maybe the problem can be isolated.

Comment: Thanks I will address your comments in an edit in the OP.

Comment: Okay and also I tried the command 'sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID' and in the output I see my centurylink server. However, I do not see it in the GUI wifi listing.

Comment: Is "DANG" the correct ESSID of the wifi network you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't understand what the output from iwconfig means.

Comment: This is good info.  Next step - look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and provide the output of the debug script.

Comment: Okay, I will in a moment. Also, how did you format the output in my OP? Did you just press ctrl+k after highlighting the output?

Comment: I used the "code sample" formatting which is just above the edit box.  It looks like curly brackets.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I just got the output from the script in the link you provided. It is quite long. I will edit it into the OP.

Comment: Here is the output: http://textuploader.com/5bvkt
It was too many characters to include in the OP so I uploaded it. .

Answer (score 0):

First you have network manager and wicd installed, you should uninstall wicd because both installed together will conflict with each other and wicd is not maintained well from what I know.

In interfaces you should only have:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

if you are using network manager and not running a server and according to the information from the script you are using network manager.

I have used century link, did you call them and have them walk you through setup of your modem/router? Wireless has to be enabled in the router.

If you did unplug the router for about five minutes then plug it back in.

After you have fixed the interfaces file run the following command to reset udev/rules

```
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

If it does not connect we may have to set some driver parameters.
Reboot and network manager should find all networks in range.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41231/discussion-on-answer-by-wild-man-unable-to-see-my-centurylink-wifi-network-in-ub).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with the C2000T at work and this is my solution.

1. Open the Network Settings and select "Connect to Hidden Network".
2. Enter the SSID and Passphrase of the router in question and connect.

In the future you will be able to connect to this network by selecting it from your known networks, however I have not been able to get it to automatically connect to the network.